# When can I one use an (PHP) Include or Require in a form?

Tags: php, forms

For a class that I am in I need to create a simple form that when the data is sent to the next page, it just creates text using the data entries from that previous page.  The instructions require us to use an "include" or "require" at least once.  I don't understand how one could use a require / include if the application is just Page with a form -> Submit -> Next page.

The require/include would require a third page, wouldn't it? Or am I missing something with the include/require? How should I go about incorporating one?

Comment: I don't see what `include` has to do with the number of pages.

Comment: Doesn't an include function call a file? Why would I need/want that extra file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normaly use an include to add some functionality to your program which you do not want to re-code in your program. For example to include certain libraries. You can also do it to make your code look neat by moving your functions or class definitions to include files then you add them to your script whereever needed. That being said, it is not a must condition that you can only use includes in a certain scenario. You can use them anytime. Even for simple things. For example you can have an file named includes.php which contains this

```
<?php
 $name=$_POST["name"];
?>
```

Then in your file which receives form submit, lets say process.php, you can say

```
<?php
 include "includes.php";
 echo $name;
 ?>
```

Also just a clarification of difference between include and require. In the simplest sense a script will continue to execute even if an include fails, but if a require call fails then the script will stop execution. You can also then use include_once or require_once to stop mistakenly including one file multiple times

Comment: Does include send the form data to includes.php, and then retrieve whatever that code does with the data?

Comment: If you include any file in your processing file then all the POST data will be available to that file aswell. so in the above scneraio $_POST will contain same data for includes.php and process.php, because they are same script once they go to server for processing

Comment: ohhh, figured it out! Its similar to calling/linking a javascript file or css.  Thank you so much!